# Scrollable with the mouse

Tags: vb.net, system.drawing

I have a panning on my usercontrol that for some reason if only the X or only the Y changes it will set the them back to 0. I have it where if x = 0 or y = 0 based on the change equals zero the AutoScrollPosition automatically sets it to the same position as it was before. So if AutoScrollPosition.X = -67, I set the new position in the code to be the previous AutoScrollPosition.X.

```
        `AutoScrollPosition = Point.Round(New PointF(AutoScrollPosition.X, MouseChange.Y - AutoScrollPosition.Y)) `
```

The System.Drawing.Point.AutoScrollPosition.X becomes 0 and it shouldn't change. Does anyone know why it does this? Is this a behavior that I should expected from this class and variable?

Comment: You did it correctly for Y but not for X.  You must use `-AutoScrollPosition.X`, note the negative sign.  You the property setter wants the negative values is a long story that isn't that intuitive.  Just fix it.

Comment: Why didn't you post it as a answer?

Comment: Because I don't have time to tell the long story.  Just fix it.

Comment: You can post just that in the comment. So I can accept your answer.

Comment: You can also write your own answer and accept it, feel free to use the info provided in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hans Passant answer

> You did it correctly for Y but not for X. You must use -AutoScrollPosition.X, note the negative sign.

Actual answer with code is

```
AutoScrollPosition = Point.Round(New PointF(-AutoScrollPosition.X, MouseChange.Y - AutoScrollPosition.Y))
```